# C# Web.API Stripe Error : Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, .net, stripe-payments, asp.net-web-api2

I have web.api with framework .net 4.7.2. Implemented stripe sdk 40.5.0, It works fine locally but on server giving error

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)

Server have tls 1.2 configured. Also I have tried two ways to figure out what is wrong but still getting same error

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

and

```
  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

Code looks like this

```
var customers = new CustomerService();
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
var result = customers.Create(customer);
```

Or

```
var customers = new CustomerService();
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
var result = customers.Create(customer);
```

In both ways, I am getting

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

I have used https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html to check the server settings and it return A+ result.

Looking for the suggestions or point out what doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Is there an `InnerException`? Why are you specifying the TLS level anyway, you should just let the operating system handle it. Speaking of, exactly which version and build number of Windows are you on?

Comment: Yeah one thing to understand is that right now the error likely happens when you code tries to talk to Stripe's servers. They deprecated SSLv3 and TLS1.0/1.1 years ago. It looks like your code/server/environment is trying to use a deprecated protocol so Stripe would just not respond. The ssllabs link wouldn't catch that. You can try to write code hitting https://www.howsmyssl.com/s/api.html to confirm which SSL version you're using

Comment: @Charlieface I wasn't forcing it. It start appearing after deployment then I try this way to check if it works or not.

Comment: @koopajah I checked and looks like TLS1.2 enabled on the server.

Comment: What is the Windows build number from `winver`? And what is the .NET version from the registry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full`